# Test page to verify if jQuery code works

Tags: jquery, testing

Is there a web site that allows to edit a simple HTML fragment, insert jQuery code, and verify if the jQuery code has the desired effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out http://www.jsbin.com.  Make sure you select jQuery from the "Include:" dropdown.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for; it allows me to check if the jQuery code works before to change the page of my web site, or to change the code of the module I am developing for Drupal.

Answer (score 17):

Check out http://jsfiddle.net, it allows you to test languages such as JavaScript, MooTools, jQuery, Prototype, YUI, Glow and Dojo, HTML, and CSS in an online editor. It also has a very slick, clean web2.0 interface and free registration. I highly recommend!

Answer (score 3):

I usually use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to test small snippets of jquery. Open any page you want that includes jquery, even the page of this very question, press F12 and run your snippets.

Comment: Also be sure to use FireQuery to be able to insert jQuery into any page and do more advanced diagnostics.

Comment: I will keep in mind this suggestion for when I need to debug the jQuery code for a Drupal module I am writting. The other suggested method (the web site) allows me to check the jQuery code before to modify the code I am writing.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest http://www.w3schools.com/
There are simple tutorials too. Just go to the tutorial and find "try it yourself!" button to start testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://plnkr.co/ website from which you can write and test your code. It supports for the following library.

JQuery
JQuery UI
Angular JS
React.js
Bootstrap
Backbone.js